# How can I take the portrait screenshots required by Google Play for an Android Automotive OS app?

Tags: android-automotive, androidautomotiveemulator

Per the Play Developer Console section on the store listing page you must, "Upload up to 8 Android Automotive OS screenshots. You must upload at least 2 portrait and 2 landscape screenshots. Screenshots must be PNG or JPEG, up to 8 MB each, 800 px by 1,280 px for portrait, and 1,024 px by 768 px for landscape" as part setting up the Android Automotive OS form factor.

Additionally, [the developer guide states](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/distribute#opt_in) "Note: When taking Automotive OS screenshots for your store listing, make sure to use a generic system image. Your screenshots should not reference any Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) in particular."

As such, I've been able to take the landscape screenshots using the *Automotive (1024p landscape)* hardware profile available in Android Studio after downloading one of the [generic emulator images](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#generic-images). However, there isn't a suitable portrait hardware profile available and trying to create one using the *New Hardware Profile* button in the *Virtual Device Configuration* window doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

---

Starting with the most recent Android Studio Canary release (Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Canary 9), there is a hardware profile named **Automotive Portrait** bundled in Android Studio that is the right resolution for Play Store screenshots.

[image]

Original

---

It looks custom hardware profiles work with the new API 33 emulator image since it doesn't include the Play Store and thus doesn't need to use a skin that's been certified for the Play Store (like the 1024p landscape skin).

To take portrait screenshots using this version of the emulator, I created the following hardware profile:

[image: Configure hardware profile screen in Android Studio. Device name is "Automotive (1280p portrait)", Device Type is "Android Automotive", Screen Size is "8" inch, Resolution is "800" x "1280", Supported device states is only "Portrait", no cameras are enabled, proximity sensor is disabled]

Then I created a virtual device using that hardware profile and the API 33 Android Automotive with Google APIs system image.

Sample screenshot:

[image: 1280p screenshot]

Since the climate controls were overlapping, I used `adb shell wm size 1200x1920` (1.5x the resolution) to change the resolution of the emulator (but the screenshots still are taken at 1280p)

[image]